# How to add a delay to bot responses, so it feels more real in Microsoft Bot Framework Node.js?

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

Is there a way to add a bit of a delay to the responses? So the bot feels more real, like if it was typing? Just a little bit.
Right now the reaction from testers has been that it’s too fast.
Which is great, but… feels too “cold”. With a little time where it looks like the bot is typing, it would feel a bit more warm and fuzzy:  :)

I need to add delay between two lines

```
    session.send("Account created successfully");
    session.send("Please login");
```

Below is the full code

```
var restify = require('restify');
var builder = require('botbuilder');
var botbuilder_azure = require("botbuilder-azure");

// Setup Restify Server
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat connector for communicating with the Bot Framework Service
var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword,
    openIdMetadata: process.env.BotOpenIdMetadata 
});

// Listen for messages from users 
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);

bot.on('conversationUpdate', (message) => {
    if (message.membersAdded) {
        message.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
            if (identity.id === message.address.bot.id) {
                bot.beginDialog(message.address, 'accountCheck');
            }
        });
    }
});

bot.dialog('accountCheck', [
    function (session, results, next) {

         session.send("Account created successfully");
         session.send("Please login");

    }
]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "",
    {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

Comment: Use `session.sendTyping()`. From my experience, artificial delays can also lead your users to think there are performance problems.

Comment: I need 2 seconds delay. So, it's not a problem. session.sendTyping() is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `timeout` on your client side or backend side.

```
function (session, results, next) {

    session.send("Account created successfully. Wait 10 seconds...");
    setTimeout(function() {
            session.send("Please login");
    }, 10000); //10 seconds
}
```

Comment: @VigneswaranA Can you show us your structure and codes on node.js?

Comment: @VigneswaranA I have changed. Can you try it?

Comment: @VigneswaranA can you apply?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162409/discussion-between-vigneswaran-a-and-hurricane).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `session.delay()`

```js
bot.dialog('accountCheck', [
    function (session, results, next) {

         session.send("Account created successfully");
         // 0.5 sec delay between messages
         session.delay(500)
         session.send("Please login");

    }
]).endConversationAction("stop",
    "",
    {
        matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
        // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
    }
);
```

see the docs:
https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.session.html#delay

Answer (score 2):

**Bot framework SDK v4:**

```
await turnContext.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing })
```

[Documentation link SDK v4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-activities-entities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=js#typing)

**Bot Framework SDK v3:**

```
session.sendTyping()
```

[Documentation link SDK v3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-typing-indicator?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Answer (score 2):

The way I have implemented this using nodejs SDK 4.0 is to use `ActivityTypes.Typing` in SendActivities as below

```
await context.sendActivities([
{type: ActivityTypes.Typing},
{type: 'delay', value:2000},
{type: ActivityTypes.Message, text: 'Bot Response goes here is only text else send attachments as reply'}])
```

Try to add above code in [Change SendActivity to SendActivities with dealy](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs/02.echo-bot)
Try testing in emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding delay, you can just send a typing indicator

```
session.sendTyping();
```

More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-typing-indicator

Comment: Not sure what that means... the typing indicator works well it will also depends on the operations you are doing next. As I pointed and also pointed in the comments, adding a delay is not a good practice

Comment: be aware that the session.sendTyping() doesn't work for every channel. Maybe that's why it is not working for @VigneswaranA